# Intern-runner cannot find dijit-intern-helper module

Tags: node-modules, intern

I just started to try Intern for functional tests and I'm not able to use the module dijit-intern-helper for my tests on a standalone selenium server. Here's my define function:

```
define(function(require) {
    var registerSuite = require('intern!object');
    var expect = require('intern/chai!expect');
    var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
    var dijit = require('intern/dojo/node!dijit-intern-helper/helpers/dijit');
//things
});
```

and this is the error I get

```
~$ intern-runner config=tests/self.intern
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Error: Cannot find module 'dijit-intern-helper/helpers/dijit'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename  <module.js:325:15>
  at Function.Module._load  <module.js:276:25>
  at Module.require  <module.js:353:17>
  at require  <internal/module.js:12:17>
  at Object.load  <../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/browser_modules /dojo/node.ts:56:11>
  at injectPlugin  <../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:711:6>
  at injectModule  <../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:733:3>
  at Array.forEach  <native>
  at forEach  <../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:265:29>
  at <../../../usr/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:753:5>
```

I cloned the [Git repository](https://github.com/sitepen/dijit-intern-helper) in node_modules global directory (and to be sure even in the test-file directory and in my home directory), but still it can't find it. Anybody knows the module or can provide some suggestion?

Comment: i would submit an issue with them. the package isn't in the npm registry and you are following their example. it's also a project that was recently open-sourced and hasn't got many commits since- probably an internal tool that hasn't been widely tested.

Comment: I have been able to install the module globally from npm typing
    _npm install -g https://github.com/SitePen/dijit-intern-helper.git_
after that the module was made available from the runner without any change needed